# SSID password vs pre shared key

Tags: ieee-802.11

Can someone please explain in very straight forward terms the difference in the SSID password vs a pre shared key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSID password *is* a pre-shared key.

"pre" because it needs to be known before starting a connection, "shared" because all parties use the same and "key" because it's used for encryption.

Comment: Yup, just different terms for the same thing. 'Pre-shared Key' sounds intimidating to the average consumer/user but 'password' is a commonly used term so it became more popular in common usage for support documents and user oriented information/interface.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not a noobie at networking but this term in wlans always boggles me.